# How do I use mouseover for an element hidden behind an invisible element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a button that is a rectangle and text and an invisible rectangle on top. The invisible rectangle helps make sure that a user can click anywhere on the button, including over the word `PLAY`.

The invisible rectangle is preventing my `.on("mouseover")` effect from working, which changes the color of the button.

This is my code -

```
// svg element
var ticker = d3.select("#ticker").select("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 50);

// group for button elements
ticker = d3.select("#ticker").select("svg")
    .attr("class", "ticker")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .append("g")

// button with color
ticker.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "pauseplay")
    .attr("x", "120")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("height","30")
    .attr("width","100")
    .attr("rx","5")
    .style("fill","#FF5960")
    .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ff7b7b"); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill", "#FF5960"); })

  // button text
  ticker.append("text")
    .attr("class","btn-text")
    .attr("x","150")
    .attr("y","20")
    .text("PAUSE")
    .style("fill","white")

  // invisible button
  ticker.append("rect")
  .attr("class","play")
  .attr("x", "120")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("height","30")
  .attr("width","100")
  .style("opacity","0")
  .on("click", function() {
    PAUSED = !PAUSED;
      t.stop();
      // Play it.
      if (!PAUSED) {
        ticker.selectAll(".btn-text").text("PAUSE")
        timer();    }
      // Pause it.
      else {
        ticker.selectAll(".btn-text").text("PLAY")
      }     })
```

I'd like for the user to be able to hover anywhere, but also have the color change on mouseover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bending over backwards, you don't need that invisible rectangle. Just set the text's `pointer-events` to `none` and add the event listener to the visible rectangle.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
// svg element
var ticker = d3.select("#ticker").select("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 50);

// group for button elements
ticker = d3.select("#ticker").select("svg")
  .attr("class", "ticker")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .append("g")

// button with color
ticker.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "pauseplay")
  .attr("x", "120")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("height", "30")
  .attr("width", "100")
  .attr("rx", "5")
  .style("fill", "#FF5960")
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ff7b7b");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#FF5960");
  })
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("click")
  })

// button text
ticker.append("text")
  .attr("class", "btn-text")
  .attr("x", "150")
  .attr("y", "20")
  .text("PAUSE")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="ticker">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to create a hover function trigerred by the invisible button (you have to add IDs) like for example :

```
ticker.append("rect")
.attr("class", "pauseplay")
.attr("id","myID")
.attr("x", "120")
.attr("y", "0")
.attr("height","30")
.attr("width","100")
.attr("rx","5")
.style("fill","#FF5960")
.on("mouseout", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill", "#FF5960"); })

 // invisible button
ticker.append("rect")
.attr("class","play")
.attr("x", "120")
.attr("y", "0")
.attr("height","30")
.attr("width","100")
.style("opacity","0")
.on("mouseover", function() { d3.select("#myID").style("fill", "#ff7b7b"); })
.on("click", function() {
PAUSED = !PAUSED;
  t.stop();
  // Play it.
  if (!PAUSED) {
    ticker.selectAll(".btn-text").text("PAUSE")
    timer();    }
  // Pause it.
  else {
    ticker.selectAll(".btn-text").text("PLAY")
  }     })
```